# How to open new tab instead of new window in Chrome in java scripts

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Using this below code I am able to open new tab along with the URL..in Firefox..but same code when  I am trying to open in Chrome its opening new window which I don't want new window ..I want new tab in case of chrome

Here is my code:

```
> window.open(this.getJavaURL +
                        ((this.returnPage != null) ?
                        ('&returnPage=' + this.returnPage) : '') +
                        ((this.locale != null) ?
                        ('&locale=' + this.locale) : '') +
                        ((this.brand != null) ?
                     ('&brand=' + this.brand) : ''),'_new');
```

Can you please help me..

Comment: Instead of "_new", you can use "_newtab"

Comment: I tried with that but still i am getting the new window..

Comment: This depends on the browser settings, you can't probably change this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/1935077

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open url in new tab using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use `_blank` instead of "_new"

It will instruct the browser to create a new browser tab or window when the user clicks on the link.

As per [reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#browsing-context-names): **_new** is not valid

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eH9tw/

Comment: _blank actually causes the problem. Just removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me. Just

```
    window.open('http://google.com');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HFeQj/

Answer (score 0):

Wether a new window or new tab is openend is based upon your browser configuration, within the browser you can set to always open popups in new tabs.

_new might break it and always open a window, _blank is the way to go like Satpal says

Answer (score 0):

it is depends on `chrome` and `firefox` tab setting.

For open new tab, you can write as below:

```
 window.open('http://google.com');
```

if new tab set as new window then it will open in new window, else it will open in new tab.

Comment: Best answer period!